# Usage de "l’avenir appartient à ceux qui se lèvent tôt"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Searching how to convey in French the meaning of the English idiom *[the early bird catches the worm](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/early-bird-catches-the-worm)* I found *[l'avenir appartient à ceux qui se lèvent tôt](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%E2%80%99avenir_appartient_%C3%A0_ceux_qui_se_l%C3%A8vent_t%C3%B4t)*. E.g.

> The admissions in this college get filled in very early. If you really want to enroll your son here then you should remember that *the early bird catches the worm* and the late comers get nothing.

> Les admissions dans cette université se remplissent très tôt. Si vous voulez vraiment inscrire votre fils ici, vous devez vous rappeler que *l'avenir appartient à ceux qui se lèvent tôt*
> et que les retardataires n'obtiennent rien.

Can one use colloquially the idiom *l'avenir appartient à ceux qui se lèvent tôt* or is it considered outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my point of view, your translation is very correct. The expression is commonly used in French, and I would even say that it is a very popular one.

---

De mon point de vue, votre traduction est tout à fait correcte. L'expression est couramment utilisée en français, et je dirai même que c'est une expression très populaire.

Comment: Merci ! NB on préfère se tutoyer chez FSE:-)!

Comment: Ça marche ! (je suis passé à l'anglais pour éviter tout soupçon ;))

Comment: Je me suis permis de modifier ta réponse et ajouter la version française de ta réponse qui était déjà bien:-)!

Comment: Merci ! Je ne sais pas trop s'il faut parler français ou anglais sur ce forum...

Comment: On avait récemment une discussion sur ça. See here:  https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/questions-coming-from-natives-in-french-or-in-english

Comment: BTW, Bienvenue chez FSE et bravo pour tes contributions fondées sur https://chrplr.github.io/openlexicon/ (nombre des lettres).

Answer (score 2):

*L'avenir appartient à ceux qui se lèvent tôt* is certainly the most pertinent French equivalent to *the early bird catches the worm*.

It conveys a very similar meaning and tone, even though it is far from a literal translation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm French I confirm this is perfectly fine.
The idea behind it is that people waking earlier would have more time to work (and reach success). It was at a time agriculture was predominant and working earlier meant being more productive.
Regards.